# Коротша назва вправи "згинання та розгинання рук в упорі лежачи"

Tags: росіянізм, одним-словом

Досить часто можна побачити, що назву вправи "згинання (та розгинання) рук в упорі лежачи" [скорочують](http://fp-norm.com/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2/%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6/) до "віджимання".

СУМ же дещо [не погоджується](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidzhymannja) із такою назвою цієї вправи:

> **ВІДЖИМА́ННЯ**, я, сер. Дія за значенням **віджимати** й **віджиматися 1**.

Де, в свою чергу:

> **[ВІДЖИМА́ТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidzhymaty)**, аю, аєш, недок.,
>
> 1. Вичавлювати рідину з чого-небудь. *Свіжі ягоди протирають, віджимають сік (Технологія приготування їжі, 1957, 105).*
> 2. Перучи, стискати та викручувати білизну тощо. *Мотря стала оджимать сорочки з відмоки, а Кайдашиха навіть хати не вимела (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 285);*
> 3. техн. Послаблювати тиск якого-небудь затискача.

і, відповідно:

> **[ВІДЖИМА́ТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidzhymatysja)**, ається, недок., **ВІДЖА́ТИСЯ**, відіжметься, док.
>
> 1. Витікати внаслідок стискання (про рідину).

Скоріше за все, дане скорочення є калькою з російського "[отжиматься](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/144322)".

А от чи є якась коротка назва цієї вправи в українській, чи правильно лише повністю її називати?

Comment: [Парубій виклав відео, як **відтискається** від підлоги 22 рази](https://tsn.ua/ukrayina/parubiy-viklav-video-yak-vidtiskayetsya-vid-pidlogi-22-razi-871290.html)

Comment: @Yola: [ВІДТИСКА́ННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidtyskannja), Дія за значенням відтискати. -> [ВІДТИСКА́ТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidtyskaty) див. відтискувати. -> [ВІДТИСКУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidtyskuvaty), ую, уєш 1. Натискаючи, віддаляти, відсувати когось від кого-, і чого-небудь. :-) Але кінець цього логічного ланцюжка в принципі не суперечить такому вживанню, дякую!

Answer (score 7):

Використовують два варіанти **віджимання** і **відтискання**.

- ["віджимання від підлоги"](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&*) - 8830
- ["відтискання від підлоги"](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&*) - 1310

обидва пошуки саме в лапках.

Могилянка використовує [відтискання](http://www.sport.ukma.edu.ua/doki/norm_snv.html). Вікіпедія - [віджимання](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Ось [цікаве обговорення](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/1291606.html).

І дійсно, не зрозуміло, чому віджимання чи відтискання має означати таку дію. Чому не, наприклад, **відштовхування**?

---

Цікавий варіант перекладу "жим лежа" - [Вивага лежачи](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Answer (score 1):

#### «Віджиматися» і «віджимання»

«Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…):

> **[ВІДЖИМА́ТИСЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12533&page=414)**, а́юся, а́єшся, *недок.*, **ВІДЖА́ТИСЯ**, відіжму́ся, віді́жме́шся, *док.*
>
> <…>
>
> **2.** Піднімати та опускати тулуб із положення лежачи за допомогою згинання і розгинання рук; відтискуватися, відтискатися.
>
> > *Із води тільки-но вискочив і ну гімнастику робити — присідає, на руках од землі оджимається, підстрибує — як хлопчик* <sub>(В. Нестайко)</sub>;
> >
> > *Я віджимався від підлоги в кращому випадку раз на тиждень, а то й два* <sub>(Л. Дереш)</sub>;
> >
> > *Три рази віджався [Прошка] на руках від долівки, тримаючи рівними в струну ноги* <sub>(Ю. Логвин)</sub>.
>
> <…>
>
> ---
>
> **[ВІДЖИМА́ННЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12531&page=414)**, я, *с.* Дія за знач. **віджима́ти** і **віджима́тися** 1, 2; відтискування, відтискання.
>
> > <…>;
> >
> > *Нормою для старшокласника є десять віджимань від підлоги* <sub>(з газ.)</sub>.

#### «Відтискатися» і «відтискання»

«Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…):

> **[ВІДТИ́СКУВАТИСЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14028&page=454)**, уюся, уєшся, **ВІДТИСКА́ТИСЯ**, а́юся, а́єшся, *недок.*, **ВІДТИ́СНУТИСЯ**, нуся, нешся, *док.*
>
> <…>
>
> **3.** Те саме, що **віджима́тися** 2.
>
> > *Молоді жителі намагалися поставити рекорд міста: найбільша кількість людей, які одночасно відтиснуться від землі п'ять разів* <sub>(з газ.)</sub>.
>
> ---
>
> **[ВІДТИСКА́ННЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14023&page=453)**, я, *с.* Дія за знач. **відтиска́ти** і **відтиска́тися** 3.
>
> > <…>
> >
> > *У Бучачі поставили масовий рекорд з відтискання від землі* <sub>(з газ.)</sub>.

Comment: Не розумію, навіщо (1) давати посилання на **те само джерело** (СУМ), що наводить asker; (2) у чому смисл наведення словникових статей? **якою взагалі є відповідь**, яку ви хочете донести до ОПа і читачів? (3) у чому смисл цієї відповіді, якщо наведені словникові статті не додають ніякого сенсу порівняно **з іншою відповіддю**, яка вже існує?

Comment: @bytebuster, (1) я дивилась у СУМ-11, а ця відповідь дає посилання на СУМ-20, (2) наведені не повні словникові статті, а лише релевантні приклади, (3) хіба мають відповіді на одне питання ДОКОРІННО різнитися? **be nice**